# Как запускать код в pycharm по секциям?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Как осуществляется деление файла на секции кода в pycharm (python)? В matlab отдельная секция запускается c помощью %%

[image]

Comment: Функции не могут быть аналогом?

Comment: Обрати взор на jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальная фича для этого, называется "Editor Cells":

1. **View | Scientific Mode** (работает только в нем)
2. `# %%` для разделения ячеек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавлю, что эта фича есть только в PyCharm Professional.